# React select is not selecting option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

https://codesandbox.io/s/o7z5rxmq4z

I have the code sandbox attached and it is a simplified version of my actual app. I tried clicking on the options but none of them is being selected in the React Select v1 options.

This is my container file. If I remove the `val` in `return( <div> <SelectComponent/>` which is the value of the select component and it will show whatever I chose but I need the value props. I need the value props so that I can submit the value to my server.

Also if I replace `await this.setState({ val: event.value })` with `await this.setState({ val: event.val })`, the component will show the chosen option but the `val` will be undefined.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: null
    };
  }

  handleChange = async event => {
    event !== null
      ? await this.setState({ val: event.value })
      : await this.setState({ val: null });
  };
  render() {
    let fruitArray = [
      { value: "apple", label: "Apple" },
      { value: "orange", label: "Orange" },
      { value: "watermelon", label: "Watermelon" }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectComponent
          val={this.state.val}      
          select_id="fruit_select_id"
          select_options={fruitArray}
          select_placeholder="Choose a fruit"
          handle_change={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my select component file. I tried this with a stateless version too but the outcome are the same, nothing is being selected.

```
class SelectComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      select_id,
      select_options,
      handle_change,
      select_placeholder,
      val
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          value={val}
          id={select_id}
          name={select_id}
          options={select_options}
          onChange={handle_change}
          placeholder={select_placeholder}
          isClearable
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Select` component wants the entire selected option object as the `value` prop. If you put the entire object in state instead of just the `value` property, it will work.

```
handleChange = option => {
  this.setState({ val: option });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - no reason for any of the async/await stuff.  That will just muck with React.

```
handleChange = event => this.setState({ val: event.value });
```

2 - You're passing `val` to your `SelectComponent` but you need to pass `value`;

```
<SelectComponent
      value={this.state.val}      
      select_id="fruit_select_id"
      select_options={fruitArray}
      select_placeholder="Choose a fruit"
      handle_change={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: It is true that I don't need them and I removed the async/await from my code. Your code works too for showing the chosen option but when I tried to reset the option it doesn't work (which is not asked in the post). @Tholle answer works for me on everything and I thank you for your effort.